# Commit cmake autogen makefiles/project files to git repo

Tags: git, makefile, cmake

If I have cmake build system that generate makefiles and project files, should I commit and push the makefiles to git repo? What are advantages and disadvantages of this?

If not, then after each pull and before build we need to generate all again using cmake?

Also, if I generated makefiles and build target, and then changed source file and then generated makefiles again (which is unnecessary), will cmake know what is already up to date? Or it will build all from scratch again?

Comment: "then after each pull and before build we need to generate all again using cmake" - Exactly. " if I generated makefiles and build target, and then changed source file and then generated makefiles again (which is unnecessary), will cmake know what is already up to date?" - CMake will generate makefiles, which will care about detecting the changes in the source files.

Comment: You should never check build products into your repo. Checking them in only generates diff noise and lets files become out of sync, leading to errors.

Answer (score 4):

In a CMake-based project, running `cmake` is not just a normal and expected part of the build process, but a *required* one.  It prepares build supports and data (project file / makefile / etc.) that are customized to the build machine.  Committing those generated artifacts helps ***no one***, and it needlessly opens an avenue for confusion and user error (using the versions from the repository instead of generating new).

There is a school of thought that argues that nothing that can be (re)built automatically should be committed.  I do not go so far myself, but certainly there's no point in committing anything that *must be* (re)built.

Comment: I've understood that I shall not commit/push cmake autogen makefiles to the repository.

What I did not understood is if I generated makefiles, and then performed changes to the code that will require changes in the makefiles, how will the new makefiles I will create now know what was already built?

Comment: That's a *completely* separate question, @user28282, but it has a fairly simple answer.  `make` knows what has already been built by *looking*.  The `makefile` tells it what targets are to be built, so `make` does not have to guess.  The makefile also tells it what the prerequisites for each file are, so it can determine (recursively) which targets that are already present are out of date with respect to the sources (by timestamp).  These are some of `make`'s core features.